# How to call a javascript function from if statement of Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I want to call a javascript function from if statement of Laravel Blade.
Is it possible?

```
@if(compareParent())
   Print Something
@endif
```

Javascript:

```
function compareParent() {
    $(".CategoryIDForModal").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data(id);
    var parent_id = $('.subcategoryPID').text();

     console.log(id.id + " Parent: " + parent_id);
     if(id==parent_id)
    return true;
     else
    return false;
     })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `@if` blade statement is evaluated **server side** and from a `php` processor, `javascript` is evaluated **client side**.

So you need to have a `compareParent()` function defined in **php** if you don't want to raise an error.